# Android room insert command not storing in database

Tags: android, insert, android-room

I am implementing an application where sensor data are being queried, stored in a txt file and afterwards stored in room database. The issue i am having is although i am getting the sensor data and store them in a room object:

```
@Entity(tableName = "sensor_data_table")
data class SensorData(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_data_id")
    var id : Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_accelerometer_X_axis")
    var accelerometer_sensor_data_X : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_accelerometer_Y_axis")
    var accelerometer_sensor_data_Y : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_accelerometer_Z_axis")
    var accelerometer_sensor_data_Z : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_temperature_sensor")
    var temperature : Float?  = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_gyroscope_sensor_X_axis")
    var gyroscope_sensor_data_X : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_gyroscope_sensor_Y_axis")
    var gyroscope_sensor_data_Y : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_gyroscope_sensor_Z_axis")
    var gyroscope_sensor_data_Z : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_linear_acceleratior_X_axis")
    var linear_acceleration_sensor_data_X : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_linear_acceleratior_Y_axis")
    var linear_acceleration_sensor_data_Y : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_linear_acceleratior_Z_axis")
    var linear_acceleration_sensor_data_Z : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_orientation_sensor_X_axis")
    var orientation_sensor_data_X : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_orientation_sensor_Y_axis")
    var orientation_sensor_data_Y : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_orientation_sensor_Z_axis")
    var orientation_sensor_data_Z : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_rotation_sensor_X_axis")
    var rotation_sensor_data_X : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_rotation_sensor_Y_axis")
    var rotation_sensor_data_Y : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_rotation_sensor_Z_axis")
    var rotation_sensor_data_Z : Float? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_rotation_sensor_Scalar")
    var rotation_sensor_data_Scalar : Float? = null,
@ColumnInfo(name = "sensor_data_timestap")
var timeStamp : String? = null
```

)

with the relevant code in MainActivity:

```
var id = roomDB.getCount()
var sensorData = SensorData(id + 1 , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileAccelX)
    , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileAccelY), java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileAccelZ) ,
    null , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileGyroX) ,
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileGyroY) , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileGyroZ) ,
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileLinAccelX) , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileAccelY) ,
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileAccelZ) , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(filePitch) ,
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileRoll) , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileAzimuth) ,
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileRotationX) , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileRotationY) ,
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileRotationZ) , java.lang.Float.parseFloat(fileRotationScalar),
    TimeStamp)

            roomDB.insert(sensorData)
```

the command is executed, although i am not getting an error of any kind, the data are not stored in the database.

Here is the code which instantiates the room database:

```
@Database( entities = [SensorData::class] , version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class SensorDataDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun sensorDataDao() : SensorDataDAO


    companion object {

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE : SensorDataDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context) : SensorDataDatabase?
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            var instance : SensorDataDatabase? = INSTANCE
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context , SensorDataDatabase::class.java , "sensor_database").build()
            }
            return instance
        }
    }

    }
}
```

The insert command on the database repository

```
suspend fun insert(sensorData : SensorData)
{
    db.insertSensorData(sensorData)
}
```

And on the data access object:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertSensorData(sensorData: SensorData)
{

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Lampros

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert the value into the database because room doesn't support ArrayList type.

Write `TypeConverter` for your `ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>` type:
(Doc reference)
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

You can use json serialization library for convert your type to string, like Gson or Jackson.

Also, may be your Dao isn't interface, so Dao must be interface and you don't have to define a function